# Make main algorithm / pseudocode from C language

Tags: c, pseudocode

How to make algorithm / pseudocode from this code?

this code is C language program that count number of space in a word.

I don't know how to make pseudocode from this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void checkSpace(char word[])
{
    int i;
    int numberspace=0;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(word);i++)
    {
        if(word[i] == ' ')
        {
           numberspace++;
        }
    }

    printf ("Your word have space : %d",numberspace);
}


int main()
{
    char nama[50] = "george";
    checkKata("george lim");

    getchar(); return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) understand what the program does. 2) describe what the program does.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal standard of pseudocode. Just explain what the program does in English.

```
for i from 0 to the size of the word:
   if the ith character is a space, ....
```